# Comparing user input to mysql database value

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void datuieguve(){
    Scanner ievads = new Scanner(System.in);
    String lietotIn = ievads.next();
//  String paroleIn = ievads.next();
    try {           
        quer = savien.createStatement();
        String kverijs = "select lietotajvards from lietotaji where lietotajvards = '" +lietotIn+ "';";
        rezult = quer.executeQuery(kverijs);
        System.out.println(rezult.next());
        String lietotajvards = rezult.getString("lietotajvards");

        if (rezult.equals(lietotIn))
        {
            System.out.println("Yup");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Nope");
        }   
    } catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Kluuda: " +ex); 
    }
    ievads.close();
}
```

Hi guys, I'm trying to create a code that will take user input and compare it with mysql database value. The problem is, it's not working and I'm stuck. I'd appreciate if someone could figure out what's wrong with my code and give me some tips or something, because I can't  :)

I think I got down the connection part but the comparison is driving me nuts.

Comment: rezult is the ResultSet http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html and will never equals String lietotIn, what you get from the db is in the String lietotajvards,

Comment: For the connection part, you should consider closing connection, statements and resultset,,, I would go for some simple examples: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: Removed superfluous whitespace, and tidied up indentation and alignment issues

Answer (score 0):

> Make these changes  on your code :

```
  while(rezult.next()){
     String lietotajvards = rezult.getString("lietotajvards");


            if(lietotajvards.equals(lietotIn))
            {
                System.out.println("Yup");
            }
            ...
    }
```

> Edit:
>   Its good practice to use prepared statement instead of create statement.

**Ex:**

```
Connection db = con.getConnection();
try {
  PreparedStatement ps = ...;
  try {
    ResultSet rs = ...
    try {
      ...
    }
    finally {
      rs.close();
    }
  } 
  finally {
    ps.close();
  }
} 
finally {
  db.close();
}
```

Comment: How can this work: (rezult.equals(lietotIn)) a ResultSet compared to a String? no need to compare....

Comment: Sorry ..these words look little strange to me.. :)